# Mocha Test Exception occurred while loading your tests

Tags: javascript, testing, vue.js, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

[Console output from error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moMGr.png)

I'm experiencing a problem with testing my Vue.js project. We have mocha-webpack to compile and run the test files. The code compiles but results in a `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error.

My coworkers and Travis CI are able to compile and run the test files. I even cloned this repo into another folder but I still have the same resutl. I think it may have something to do with the dependencies installed globally but I'm not sure if there's some conflict.

[Global dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKlwP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason I had this issue was because I was testing an async function but my node version was v6.9. After I upgraded by node to v10, I successfully ran my tests.